# Hashtable explanation

Tags: python, database

```
class HashTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 11
        self.slots = [None] * self.size
        self.data = [None] * self.size

def put(self,key,data):
  hashvalue = self.hashfunction(key,len(self.slots))

  if self.slots[hashvalue] == None:
    self.slots[hashvalue] = key
    self.data[hashvalue] = data
  else:
    if self.slots[hashvalue] == key:
      self.data[hashvalue] = data  #replace
    else:
      nextslot = self.rehash(hashvalue,len(self.slots))
      while self.slots[nextslot] != None and \
                      self.slots[nextslot] != key:
        nextslot = self.rehash(nextslot,len(self.slots))

      if self.slots[nextslot] == None:
        self.slots[nextslot]=key
        self.data[nextslot]=data
      else:
        self.data[nextslot] = data #replace
```

I've been reading this bit of data structure on hashtable, and need explanation on this part below.

If key is already present, why is data being replaced?

```
if self.slots[hashvalue] == key:
  self.data[hashvalue] = data  #replace
```

Also, can someone explain this part? Nextslot would be empty slot.
And we just rehash and if it's not empty and key is not present, rehash again?

```
  nextslot = self.rehash(hashvalue,len(self.slots))
  while self.slots[nextslot] != None and \
                  self.slots[nextslot] != key:
    nextslot = self.rehash(nextslot,len(self.slots))
```

Comment: Please describe the difference between the expected and the observed behavior. It would be best to give example input and output.

Answer (score 1):

> If key is already present, why is data being replaced?

That's just how hash tables normally behave, because people usually want them to behave that way. Setting a key that is already present "overwrites" the previous value.

> Also, can someone explain this part? Nextslot would be empty slot.

Nextslot is not guaranteed to be empty, it's just the next slot we're going to check. Think of it this way: As long as the slot we're checking is taken by a *different* key, we need to keep trying the next slot (which is picked by rehashing). If we find an empty slot, great, use it. If we find that the slot is taken but it's the same key, then overwrite it. So that loop keeps rehashing until it finds a slot that is empty OR a slot that has the same key (which we can overwrite).

Comment: Ok. Say that you find a same key, and you overwrite the data. What happens to the key(and data) that you just replaced?

Comment: @user5977290 The old data for that key is just lost. The key.. well you didn't change it, so it stays the same.

Comment: isn't that a collision though? If key is same that is. Isn't that why next empty slot is being searched for?

Comment: @user5977290 If the key is the same, that is not considered a collision. From Wikipedia: "Ideally, the hash function will assign each key to a unique bucket, but most hash table designs employ an imperfect hash function, which might cause hash collisions where the hash function generates the same index for more than one key." A collision means two different keys hashed to the same index. If you look at the loop, it only keeps searching if the key is _different_. If it's the same, it stops searching and overwrites the data.